# Need to write SQL query that creates a "Date" column and fills all rows with current Date

Tags: sql, ssms, rational-team-concert

I currently have a SQL query that selects and creates a report from a specified SQL Database (Rational Data Warehouse). This report will merely include the columns I have selected from different tables, nothing else.

I want to add a command to the query that creates a "Date" column in the report and then fills every row that does not have nulls with the current date. Is there such a query function that could do this?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Doing a bit more research I've realized that that I don't think that it is actually possible to add brand new columns in Jazz's Report Builder. So I think now my question is moot :(

Answer (score 0):

I've never used RDW but most SQL database systems have a function that returns the current date/time. To include the output of a function in a query output you call the function and give it an alias

if i had a query of:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname
FROM person
```

and i wanted the date in there, in eg MS SQL server i would do:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, getutcdate() as curdate
FROM person
```

have a look in the manual for your database to see what it's "current datetime" function is (i did have a quick google but didn't find a SQL dbms called "rational data warehouse")